# Scala: Calculate Min, Max, Average with conditions

Tags: scala, case-class, calculation

I have a case class defined like this:

```
def case_class(): Unit = {
   case class StockPrice(quarter : Byte,
                      stock : String,
                      date : String,
                      open : Double,
                      high : Double,
                      low : Double,
                      close : Double,
                      volume : Double,
                      percent_change_price : Double,
                      percent_change_volume_over_last_wk : Double,
                      previous_weeks_volume : Double,
                      next_weeks_open : Double,
                      next_weeks_close : Double,
                      percent_change_next_weeks_price : Double,
                      days_to_next_dividend : Double,
                      percent_return_next_dividend : Double
                     )
```

Here are the data of the case class:

```
1,IBM,3/4/2011,162.36,164.31,159.41,161.83,21549118,-0.326435,0.491083418,21443811,161.60,162.43,0.513614,63,0.463449
1,IBM,3/11/2011,161.60,167.72,158.85,162.43,31119857,0.513614,44.41359967,21549118,161.16,155.89,-3.27004,56,0.461737
1,IBM,3/18/2011,161.16,161.98,151.71,155.89,41827781,-3.27004,34.40865426,31119857,157.64,162.18,2.87998,49,0.481108
1,IBM,3/25/2011,157.64,162.74,157.07,162.18,25381792,2.87998,-39.31833965,41827781,161.54,164.27,1.68998,42,0.462449
1,INTC,1/7/2011,21.01,21.21,20.27,20.66,386719626,-1.66587,0,0,20.71,21.08,1.78658,27,0.871249
1,INTC,1/14/2011,20.71,21.33,20.57,21.08,274111012,1.78658,-29.11892917,386719626,21.03,20.82,-0.998573,20,0.85389
1,INTC,1/21/2011,21.03,21.20,20.62,20.82,218479469,-0.998573,-20.29526016,274111012,21.03,21.46,2.0447,13,0.864553
```

My question is how to calculate Min, Max, Average with a condition `stock = IBM`. Thanks for your support!

My problem has been solved thanks to **@pme** and **@talex**. Thank you all!

Comment: Min, Max Average based on which attribute?

Comment: What problem do you have? You do not know how to filter lists? Or calculate min, max, avg?

Comment: @PuneethReddyV based on `stock` attribute

Comment: @talex Yes, I dont know how to calculate Min, Max, Avg with the case class like that

Comment: `stock` attribute is for filter, what is the attribute for the `mathematical operations`?

Comment: @PuneethReddyV I dont know

Comment: @jwvh Sorry. Both helped me, therefore I don't know to choose which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
val stockPrices: Seq[StockPrice]
```

You can:

```
val filtered = stockPrices
                 .filter(_.stock == "IBM") // filter for IBM
                 .map(_.open) // map to the price

val average = filtered.sum / filtered.length
val min = filtered.min
val max = filtered.max
```

Check it out on [scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/p84FSFv/1)

Comment: `val stockPrices: Seq[StockPrice]` Error: `Block cannot contain declaration`

Comment: `val average = filtered.sum/ filtered.length` got an error `No implicits found for parameter`

Comment: I dont understand, My Intellij show an error of this line `val average = filtered.sum / filtered.length` **No implicits found for parameter Numeric[String]**

Comment: That means that `open` is not a number! - Make sure that all values are a number!

Comment: Cheer. You got it right! But if all values are not a number why I can calculate `min` `max` successfully?

Comment: They are less strict what they compare - check their APIs

Comment: Would you tell me **Is ArraySeq is collection type?** What chapter do I need to focus on to learn to solve these types of question?

Comment: just google for it;) Here an example: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/understanding-scala-collections-hierarchy-cookbook

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have list of objects:

```
list: Seq[StockPrice]
```

and want to have min and max `open`

```
val min = list.map(x=>x.open).min
val max = list.map(x=>x.open).max
```

to get average you need

```
val sum = list.map(x=>x.open).sum
val count = list.size
val avg = sum / count
```

to filter it you can do folowing

```
val filteredList = list.filter(p => p.stock == 'IBM')
```

Comment: What about a condition?

Comment: @KeyJun I edited my answer. Added filtering example.

Comment: `list: Seq[StockPrice]`  You mean `val list: Seq[StockPrice]` ?

Comment: I still got an error with this line `val list: Seq[StockPrice]`

Comment: `val stockPrices: Seq[StockPrice]` Error: `Block cannot contain declaration`

Comment: It is because you need to assign something to it. I assumed that you have list of object of proper type, you should use it.

Comment: Now I got `val sum = list.map(x=>x.open).sum` got an error No implicits found for parameter

Comment: **No implicits found for parameter Numeric[String]** This error

Comment: That is common problem Check you types. May want to split `list.map(x=>x.open).sum` to two separate statement  and add explicit types.

Comment: Sorry, Can i ask one more question? Is `ArraySeq` is `collection` type?

Comment: Of course you can. The whole site is dedicated for this :) There is even special "Ask Question" button in top right corner.

Comment: **Is ArraySeq is collection type?** No it is just a small question. I dont want to post another post for this